# What is the best practice for Polymer core-menu

Tags: polymer, polymer-designer-tool

I started using the polymer core-pages and core-menu elements.
And I wan to know if I am implementing it right.

My page is simple and looks like this:

```
   <core-menu selected="0" selected="{{selected}}">
        <core-item label="Organization"></core-item>
        <core-item label="Bank Setup"></core-item>
   </core-header-panel>
   <span tool class="tabAdminPolymer_title"></span>
   <core-pages class="sss" selected="{{selected}}">
     <div class="pages">
        Hi there content1!
     </div>
   </core-pages>
```

Using Java Script on menu click event I am changing the content of the class .page
My content is backbone controls that renders using obj.render js function.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is sound but there are some simple errors which are breaking it. Please try the following corrections.

You're using the "selected" attribute twice:

```
<core-menu selected="0" selected="{{selected}}">
to
<core-menu selected="{{selected}}">
```

You're closing the wrong tag:

```
</core-header-panel>
to
</core-menu>
```

That's it. Code works otherwise.